# Help! What kind of spider is this?

Tags: species-identification, entomology, arachnology

[image]

Can anyone tell me what kind of spider this is and if it might be poisonous?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Please provide the location and an approximte size of the species. A close-up photo would be much better.

Comment: looks like it *was* a broad-faced sac spider, or something related